# iTunes Search API -- is there a way to get all apps (iPhone, iPad, Mac) for a certain keyword?

Tags: app-store, itunes-store

This seems counter-intuitive :

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

I was expecting that http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Avatar+Cameron&media=software&country=FR&limit=15 would return all apps on iTunes, regardless of the specific platform (iPhone, iPad-only, Mac).

However, it does not seem to be the case.

Is there any other way to retrieve both iPhone and iPad apps than requesting `entity=software`, then `entity=iPadSoftware`, and merge the results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a comma to separate the values for entity:

```
&entity=software,iPadSoftware
```

Comment: I still upvoted because this set me on the right track, but this trick doesn't work for me.  I get only one or the other

Answer (score 3):

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=YOURID&entity=software will give *all* software results for the YOURID in question (iPhone, iPad, Mac).

You can get YOURID by searching manually for https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=YOURCOMPANY&entity=software and then text searching on the page for "artistId"

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer from @halmstrz, you can also return results from the Mac App Store via the following addition to &entity:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=angry+birds&entity=software,iPadSoftware,macSoftware
```

Answer (score -2):

leave off the `"entity=software"` and you get iPhone results (I know it doesn't seem like you would, it seems like you'd get a mix of all 3)

then do it with `"entity=iPadSoftware"` and you get the iPad results

I do 2 separate cURLs, and then use the results of both.

Comment: I should have precised in my question: "in one request" :)